# How to load multiple WMS layers at once in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, wms

[image]Does anyone know how to load multiple WMS layers at one time in QGIS?

The attached screenshot shows all the layers available for a particular URL. Loading them all individually takes an age. In ARC you can select the top layer (containing all sub-layers) and it adds them all in hierarchical structure. QGIS seems to just crash.

QGIS version 2.16 on Windows 7.

The url is:

"http://environment.data.gov.uk/ds/wms?INTERFACE=ENVIRONMENT--9089254f-d465-11e4-9265-f0def148f590&"

Comment: Link says "Access Denied". What version of QGIS? What OS?

Comment: I can't see any screenshot.

Comment: Your url is not accessible.

Comment: Hello All, Thanks for the reply. Screen shot should be up now. It's version 2.16  running on Windows 7. The URL seems to work for me.

Comment: Also access denied. You likely need to contact the administrator for the web service.

Comment: Are you based in the UK? Perhaps access is only permitted within the UK for some reason, just a thought. Seems to work on mine as you can see from the screenshot. Any thoughts on how to add all layers at once?

Comment: How many layers are you attempting to add and how large are they? It's very possible that you are trying to load too much data at once.

Comment: I can confirm the error (UK based and I use this data a lot).  Selecting just the top layer, or a group of layers (using control+select), adds all of the WMS data into one QGIS layer and sometimes it just falls over.

Comment: Hi, I'll post the URL again just in case a character was missed for some reason. There are around 250 layers. So quite a few. As I say it seems to work in ARC so perhaps its just too much data to load at once for QGIS.

Comment: "http://environment.data.gov.uk/ds/wms?INTERFACE=ENVIRONMENT--9089254f-d465-11e4-9265-f0def148f590 &"

Comment: Can't seem to post the URL as it keeps getting abreviated when I post it. Quite sure it's correct though. Need to copy right up to the final "&" character.

Comment: I'm in the UK and can say that a GetCapabilites request works for me: https://environment.data.gov.uk/ds/wms?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&INTERFACE=ENVIRONMENT--9089254f-d465-11e4-9265-f0def148f590& also I see that this service references another url, and a GetCapabilities for that URL also works:  http://www.geostore.com/OGC/OGCInterface?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&SESSIONID=1531774591&INTERFACE=ENVIRONMENT&

Comment: I can use the GeoStore service end point `http://www.geostore.com/OGC/OGCInterface?SESSIONID=1531774591&INTERFACE=ENVIRONMENT&` in QGIS 2.16.0 and load multiple layers